# Loading SQLite extension fails on Windows 64bit Python

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

I'm writing a Python program that uses sqlite3 module on Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit.

When I try to load sqlite extension, sqlite3.OperationalError is raised (the specified procedure could not be found).

Python version is 3.3.5 for Windows 64bit from www.python.org.

Because I thought sqlite3.dll should be better linked with msvcr100.dll than the MinGW default msvcrt.dll when the resulting DLL is used with Python 3.3.x, I made a spec file to link with msvcr100dll, and built sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe with devkit MinGW 64bit as follows.

DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

The SQLite source is sqlite-amalgamation-3080403.zip

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -dumpspecs | sed "s/-lmsvcrt/-lmsvcr100/" > msvcr100.spec

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -O2 -shared -o sqlite3.dll -Wl,--out-implib=libsqlite3.dll.a -specs=msvcr100.spec sqlite3.c

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -O2 -o sqlite3.exe -specs=msvcr100.spec shell.c libsqlite3.dll.a
```

in example.py:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

# enable extension loading
con.enable_load_extension(True)

# Load the fulltext search extension
con.load_extension("./sqlite3.dll")
```

python example.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 23, in <module>
    con.load_extension("./sqlite3.dll")
sqlite3.OperationalError: 指定されたプロシージャが見つかりません。
```

The last Japanese message means the specified procedure could not be found.

**EDIT**

I found that just replacing the original sqlite3.dll shipped with Python (in Python33\DLLs) with your newly built sqlite3.dll is enough.

You don't need to do enable_load_extension() or load_extension().

You can do something like this right away.

```
con.execute("create virtual table recipe using fts3(name, ingredients)")
```

Comment: Did it work that way in the end or is the problem still unsolved?

Comment: Just using newly built sqlite3.dll solved the problem. See EDIT part.